# Python - Column-wise keep first unique value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has multiple columns that represent whether or not something had existed, but they are ordinal in nature. Something could have existed in all 3 categories, but I only want to indicate the highest level that it existed in.

So for a given row, i only want a single '1' value , but I want it to be kept at the highest level it was found at.

For this row: 
`1,1,0` , I would want the row to be changed to `1,0,0`

and this row:
`0,1,1` , I would want the row to be changed to `0,1,0`

Here is a sample of what the data could look like, and expected output:

```
import pandas as pd

#input data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'level1':[0,0,0,0,1],
                   'level2':[1,0,1,0,1],
                   'level3':[0,1,1,1,0]})

#expected output:
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'level1':[0,0,0,0,1],
                   'level2':[1,0,1,0,0],
                   'level3':[0,1,0,1,0]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies()` by assigning a 1 to the maximum index

```
df[df.filter(like='level').columns] = pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='level').idxmax(1))

   id  level1  level2  level3
0   1       0       1       0
1   2       0       0       1
2   3       0       1       0
3   4       0       0       1
4   5       1       0       0
```

Comment: A lot of good answers on this one. This one required the least code and was very simple to understand.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `numpy.zeros` and filling via `numpy.argmax`:

```
out = np.zeros(df.iloc[:, 1:].shape, dtype=int)
out[np.arange(len(out)), np.argmax(df.iloc[:, 1:].values, 1)] = 1
df.iloc[:, 1:] = out
```

#### Using `broadcasting` with `argmax`:

```
a = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
df.iloc[:, 1:] = (a.argmax(axis=1)[:,None] == range(a.shape[1])).astype(int)
```

Both produce:

```
   id  level1  level2  level3
0   1       0       1       0
1   2       0       0       1
2   3       0       1       0
3   4       0       0       1
4   5       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use advanced indexing with NumPy. Updating underlying NumPy array works here since you have a dataframe of `int` dtype.

```
idx = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).values.argmax(1)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = 0
df.values[np.arange(df.shape[0]), idx+1] = 1

print(df)

   id  level1  level2  level3
0   1       0       1       0
1   2       0       0       1
2   3       0       1       0
3   4       0       0       1
4   5       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `numpy.eye`

```
v = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
i = np.eye(3, dtype=np.int64)
a = v.argmax(1)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = i[a]
df

   id  level1  level2  level3
0   1       0       1       0
1   2       0       0       1
2   3       0       1       0
3   4       0       0       1
4   5       1       0       0
```

---

#### `cumsum` and `mask`

```
df.set_index('id').pipe(
    lambda d: d.mask(d.cumsum(1) > 1, 0)
).reset_index()

   id  level1  level2  level3
0   1       0       1       0
1   2       0       0       1
2   3       0       1       0
3   4       0       0       1
4   5       1       0       0
```